# Best practices for using typescript with node

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, build, jestjs

For react rthere is create-react-app which codifies best practices in project setup.

Something is missing in node. If I want to develop and deploy a typescript application on node.js I need at least 3 "targets":

- **start** runs a development build of the app
- **test** executes unittests (e.g. jest)
- **build** compiles the typescript to something node can understand - for deployment.

For all this functionality there are tools like [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) and [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

This all somewhat works but i get all kinds of hickups. Currently the `scripts` section in `package.json` looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src",
    "start": "yarn run nodemon -e js,json,graphqls,ts,yaml --signal SIGHUP -x ts-node src/index.js",
    "test": "rm -Rf dist/ ; yarn run ts-jest --testPathIgnorePatterns=tests/",
  },
```

But this has all kinds of issues. `tsc` uses `src/tsconfig.json`. The other two use `./tsconfig.json`. without that the output will be in `./dist/src/` and the difference in dir depth will mess up relative file access to non-source files.

`ts-node` and `tsc` seem to report different errors. For example `tsc` seems to be fine with accidentaly coexisting js and ts files while ts-node crashes with an opaque `emit error`. The contents of `./dist` confuse the other tools - thy load and execute files from `./dist` instead from `./src`.

So how do I set up a reloading development server (`yarn start`), a test runner (`yarn test`) and a production compillation (`yarn build`) all using the same configuration files, resting at the same directory depth and behaving all the same?

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. If you're asking about best practices in general, that's an off-topic. If you're asking about specific problem then focus on it. *too deep nested for relative paths to work* - the problem with nesting isn't obvious. *But this has all kinds of issues. tsc uses src/tsconfig.json* - it's unclear what the problem is. In case you need multiple configs then use tsconfig inheritance. FWIW it's not a good practice to put tsconfig to src. It's not a source file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the separation of configuration and code. I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: It looks like the problem is solely that TS wasn't configured properly rather than the setup in general. There can and likely should be several configs that extend a common one, at least for app and tests. Parts that you likely lack are `rootDir`, `exclude` and `include`.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) solution. I'm the author

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such solution that just works out of the box like create-react-app unless you find some boilerplate repositories that include everything you need and use those. You could setup webpack, it can be used for both building and developing, but configuring it may take a while, although it's easier in newer versions. Rollup is also a nice solution

Anyway, you probably don't need `-p src` option for `tsc`, this specifies root directory of your project, where the `tsconfig` lies, not the root directory of source files. This option should point to the folder where `tsconfig` is and there, in `tsconfig`, you specify where are you source files using `include` or `files` fields.

Speaking about `nodemon` it's probably a better option to run `node` instead of `ts-node` and register it as a module instead:

```
nodemon -r ts-node/register src/index.js
```

Also to clean up your `package.json` you could move command line options to `nodemon.json`. You probably can find more guides how to solve other conflicts that may happen on the internet like dealing with these nested paths. Not sure what's the problem with `dist` though, build folders aren't supposed to confuse any tools

Comment: Thanks for hinting at `nodemon.json`. I personally avoid too many different configuration files in project root and put everything in package.json. Personal taste I guess.

Comment: Since config files is the only kind of files that's expected in project root, it's not the worst place to put them. You can use a dedicated config dir for them but at least some of them like linter config and package.json are hierarchical and there will be 2 dirs cluttered with configs instead of 1.